# event function is called faster than componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling, components

My componentDidUpdate is updating state inside of the class. But when I click on the button, the onClick function is called first, so it renders old state. after i click on button second time, it works as needed. please help me to solve first click problem.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps: any, prevState: any) {
    if (prevProps.is_related !== this.props.is_related) {
      this.state.is_related = this.props.is_related
      this.setState(this.state);
    }
  }


    onDeleteCourse = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        const deleteList = this.state.selected_ids;
        this.props.dispatch(
          Actions.ApiRequest(Constants.activity.ACTIVITY_IS_RELATED, deleteList, 'activity-list-spin')
        );
        if (e && e.target && this.state.is_related) {
          this.props.dispatch(
            Actions.ShowModal({
//blablabla
            })
          );
        } else if (e && e.target && !this.state.is_related) {
          this.props.dispatch(
            Actions.ShowModal({
//blablabla
            })
          );
        }
      };
```

Comment: Try to add componentDidMount to update your state on first render

Comment: @devSpartan unfortunately componentDidMount does not accept parameters as prevProps etc